# How do I automatically increment a number in Selenium IDE (Chrome)

Tags: selenium-ide

I have been trying to create a looping script which increments a number by 1 with each loop.

These are the commands:

`Store | 1 | i |
Times | 5 | 
Execute Script | return ${i} + 1; | i |
Echo | ${i} |
End`

When the script loops, it outputs the following in the log:

`echo: 1
echo: 11
echo: 111
echo: 1111
echo: 11111`

I have tried this instead:

`Execute Script | return ${i} ++; |`

But this outputs:

`echo: 1
echo: 1
echo: 1
echo: 1
echo: 1`

Answer (score 1):

I use this command to increment iterator i

```
Execute Script|return Math.floor(${i})+1|i
```

Answer (score 0):

its abit of a long way round, but i've found that this process works:
storeEval    ¦   0    ¦  loop
echoandwait
while   ¦   ${loop}<50
execute script
storeEval    ¦  ${loop}+1   ¦   loop
endwhile

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, I wanted to increase the variable with 1 and only this command works in selenium ide 3+
Execute Script|return Math.floor(${i})+1|i